# Формулювання "це про це", "це про те" (в якості перекладу зв'язки is about...) - мають право на життя?

Tags: прийменники

Наприклад:
Ремонт - це завжди про нерви.
Про що це для тебе?

Не так давно такі конструкції почали вживати в усному мовленні, але чи доречно їх вживати в літературному?
Дякую)

Answer (score 2):

У літературній мові вживати такі конструкції геть недоречно. Та і в усному мовленні — як кальку вживають хіба що у випадку, коли обидва співрозмовники знають англійську (в інших контекстах чути не траплялося).

У тих двох випадках, які ви навели, українською можна сказати інакше: «Ремонт — це завжди нерви»; «Що це значить для тебе?».

Comment: Дякую) Думала, що я одна така "відстала"))
"Та і в усному мовленні — як кальку вживають хіба що у випадку, коли обидва співрозмовники знають англійську (в інших контекстах чути не траплялося)" - серйозно? Так наче геть усі тепер говорять...